# Can we access iPhone keychain keys and certificates from Opensssl?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, openssl

I have a task to access keys(private) and certificates from iPhone kechain using Openssl, read them and use those keys and certificates to sign, verify, encrypt and decrypt data on the iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have access only to your local app (apps) keychain. So if you want to use some certificate to authenticate you should install it firstly in your keychain.

But you can check server certificate using iOS SDK (trusted/untrusted server).

Comment: Thanks for your promt reply.
But I do have a certificate and key in my key chain.
I could access them using secitemcopymatching method call, but cant use the private key(seckeyref) for pkcs7 signature, So I used Openssl for pkcs7 signatures with a private key converted to pem file manually, but i want to access private key in key chain already installed(seckeyref) for generating signature using openssl.. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not expert in questions about OpenSSL. Mb someone will help you